# SQL Query to union all table names on a database with MySQL

Tags: mysql, union-all

I use this SQL query for find, in  database `MySql version 8.0.17`, the tables whose name corresponds to the condition indicated in the clause `LIKE`

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_name LIKE 't#_contents#_s3%#_1#_2021' ESCAPE '#';

+-------------------------+
| TABLE_NAME              |
+-------------------------+
| t_contents_s300_1_2021  |
| t_contents_s34d_1_2021  |
| t_contents_s34g_1_2021  |
| t_contents_s3sv_1_2021  |
+-------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.30 sec)
```

My question is

How to do go about for union all these tables returned by the SQL query ?

Normally I would do this mode, but I don't know first all the names of the tables and the number of the tables returned by the SQL query... the names and the number of the tables it could be variable...

I'm not the administrator of this database.
This schema is a remote hosting where I can only read..

```
SELECT
    `sUn`,
    `sUnName`,
    `contents` 'Set' 
FROM
    `t_contents_s300_1_2021` UNION ALL
SELECT
    `sUn`,
    `sUnName`,
    `contents` 'Set' 
FROM
    `t_contents_s34d_1_2021` UNION ALL
SELECT
    `sUn`,
    `sUnName`,
    `contents` 'Set' 
FROM
    `t_contents_s34g_1_2021` UNION ALL
SELECT
    `sUn`,
    `sUnName`,
    `contents` 'Set' 
FROM
    `t_contents_s3sv_1_2021` 
ORDER BY
    `sUn` ASC;
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design

Comment: @Strawberry I'm sorry but I'm not the administrator of this database. this schema is a remote hosting where I can only read...

Comment: I'm sorry too. :-(

Comment: @Strawberry maybe I can have some privileges on the scheme. if there is a job possibility what privileges should I ask the database administrator for this scheme?